# Python code can't use system variable

Tags: python

I have the following part of my code where I have a problem:

```
import os, sys
import optparse
import subprocess
import random

# we need to import python modules from the $SUMO_HOME/tools directory
try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', '..', '..', "tools")) # tutorial in tests
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ.get("$SUMO_HOME", os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "..", "..")), "tools")) # tutorial in docs
    from sumolib import checkBinary
except ImportError:
    sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME' as the root directory of your sumo installation (it should contain folders 'bin', 'tools' and 'docs')")

import traci
```

I declared SUMO_HOME as a system variable, but when I run this script I get the ImportError. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: use `os.environ.get('SUMO_HOME')`, not `os.environ.get('$SUMO_HOME')`.

Comment: I did it, no changes. Still the same error

Comment: How did you declare it?

Comment: In system variables as directory to folder with files 
D:\Folder1\Folder2

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski Does printing the value of `os.environ.get('SUMO_HOME')` in the script display the correct path?

Comment: Yes when i type in cmd %SUMO_HOME% i get correct path.

Comment: Go to the terminal and type `export`. Is SUDO_HOME listed there?

Comment: My terminal don't recognize _export_

Comment: `echo $SUMO_HOME` not export

Comment: Ok it works with echo but still don't work with my code.

Comment: No one have any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Why have you added a $? The name of the variable is `SUMO_HOME`, not `$SUMO_HOME`.

Comment: As i said moment ago i changed it to SUMO_HOME but it still don't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with it too. If I echo'ed in my terminal it showed the right path but within the python file it somehow would not find it. For me it was fixed by modifying the try-except block to:

```
# we need to import python modules from the $SUMO_HOME/tools directory
try:
    sys.path.append(<Path to tools>)
    from sumolib import checkBinary
except ImportError:
    sys.exit(
        "please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME' as the root directory of your sumo installation (it should contain folders 'bin', 'tools' and 'docs')")
```

So in my example I used this block and replaced `<Path to tools>` with `'/Users/Isabelle/sumo-0.28.0/tools'`

I know it is a late comment and you've probably solved it or moved on, but hopefully it will still help others!

Kind regards,

Isabelle

Answer (score 0):

This solution might only be for MAC OS. Not sure about other OS.
I've found what was wrong, I don't know why but there is a mistake on the number of `'..'` in the python code. You need to remove one. There need to be 3, not 4.
It should be:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', '..', "tools")) # tutorial in tests
```

instead.
The first `'..'` brings you inside the 'tutorial' folder, the second inside the 'docs' folder and the third inside the main folder where 'bin', 'tools' and 'docs' are located.